# What do we call an authority in charge of governing a village?

Tags: single-word-requests

We have municipality for cities, and government for the countries. What about villages?

Comment: In India, especially rural areas, we have "village offices"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about how local government is organised in different countries/regions, not the use of English as such.

Comment: I thought this is the same everywhere in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Municipality** — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipality)

> The territory over which a municipality has jurisdiction may encompass
>   only one populated place such as a city, town, or village... Types of municipalities within Canada include cities, district municipalities, municipal districts, municipalities, parishes, rural municipalities, towns, townships, villages, and villes among others... In the United States, "municipality" is usually understood as a city, town, village, or other local government unit, formed by municipal charter from the state as a municipal corporation.

Therefore, any type of local government, whether city, town, village or borough, are considered **municipalities**.

Bear in mind that in the various states of the US, as well as all other locations around the world, the legal definition of the various types of municipalities mentioned above may differ or overlap.

Comment: I note that OP has already over-quickly accepted this answer.  But while this answer may be correct for N. America, it is certainly not correct for the U.K.. (And, incidentally, Wikipedia is not a reliable source for this type of information because it is editable by anyone world-wide and the content will depend on the who wrote it.) ODO defines [municipality](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/municipality) as "A **town or district** that has local government:" [emphasis added]. That is more akin to UK usage, where a village would **not** be considered as a municipality.

Comment: Read the last paragraph.  And perhaps he accepted it because he was interested in North America, even though he didn't say so in the question.  Clearly, the other answer by Patrick Quinn, deals with the UK, and he could have chosen it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I read your final paragraph as referring to the quoted definition. But I was actually referring to your penultimate paragraph, and I read that as if you thought it applied world-wide. (I don't know in what sequence OP's acceptance & the additional answer occurred.  You'll note that I actually also disagree with the answer from @PatrickQuinn!)

Comment: Also it should be noted that in the US, "municipality" generally refers to the the town, city or village itself, and not the people who run it.

Answer (score 0):

In many areas of the United Kingdom, this would be the [*village council*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Village+council) or, perhaps more vaguely, the *local authority*. This depends somewhat on the politics of the country however, for example French villages are more currently run by a single mayor (a *mayorship*).

Comment: village council aka parish council.

Comment: There are many systems, with specific words. In New England (US), many villages are governed by Selectmen (elected officials) on a Board of Selectmen.

Comment: Equally valid, although perhaps again a little more vague as a parish does not necessary preclude containing either no villages, or multiple.

Comment: I live in an English village and have never heard the term *village council*.  The smallest unit of local government in England is the *Parish Council*, which can cover more than one village. I think it unlikely that a Parish Council could cover **no** villages, although it could perhaps merely cover several hamlets. *Parish Council* does **not** equate to *local authority*, at least not in common English usage: *local authority* is more commonly used to refer to the next higher tier of local government, namely *District Council* (or equivalent), but may also refer to the *County Council*. ...

Comment: ... [cont'd]  Scotland, Wales & Northern Ireland have different arrangements for their local governments.